# The Header Color is not complete/Full-Width [IMG Inside]

Tags: html, css

The color of my Header is not complete/Full width
The HTML:

```
<header class="headerstyle">
    <div id="headerstyle"></div>

        <!-- Side Navigation Bar Items -->
        <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
            <a href="languages.html">Languages</a>
            <a href="tools.html">Tools</a>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            <a href="about.html">About</a>
        </div>
        <!-- The three line Menu -->
        <span onclick="openNav()">
            <div class="menu"></div>
            <div class="menu"></div>
            <div class="menu"></div>
        </span>
</header>
```

and the CSS:

```
 .headerstyle {
        background-color: #4CBFBC;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        position: absolute;
    }


    /* The Three Line Menu */

    .menu {
        width: 25px;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: black;
        margin: 6px 0;
        padding: 2px;
        position: relative;
        left: 3px;
    }
```

[image: OUTPUT:]

Don't ask if the SideNav is not working (It needs JS),
I just need the Color of my header to be full-width/or complete (and responsive);

I suck at explanation xD;

Comment: Could you try adding to your headerstyle class width: 100%;?

Comment: What's your testing device ?

Comment: @Minar Mnr All widths of browser(small - large responsive size)

Comment: check fiddle below. does it solve your problem ?

Comment: @Minar Mnr I try it tomorrow because I need to take a rest... IM  

Comment: ha ha  ... ok :)

Comment: Just a note on semantics: Try to avoid `<a href="javascript:void(0)">` and instead use `<button type="button"></button>`... Accessibility will thank you ;)

Comment: Oh and `<span onclick="">`... That's even worse for a11y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Width: 100% in your css .
Fiddle example
 (https://jsfiddle.net/deq4ph7m/)

CSS :

```
 .headerstyle {
        background-color: #4CBFBC;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
    }


    /* The Three Line Menu */

    .menu {
        width: 25px;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: black;
        margin: 6px 0;
        padding: 2px;
        position: relative;
        left: 3px;
    }
```